# Alternative to IApplicationAssociationRegistration Interface on Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am new to the subject. If something looks unclear and needs clarification, please comment and I will try to provide more details.

I have been working on a project that was implemented a couple of years ago and needs some tuning to fit today's needs.

This Windows Desktop Application has a feature to set the app as a default, using a couple of methods of the [`IApplicationAssociationRegistration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iapplicationassociationregistration) interface.

Part of the code:

```cpp
BOOL CDefaultPrograms::SetActiveSendAllDefaults()
{
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;
    IApplicationAssociationRegistration *pAAR;

    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
                    CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration,
                    NULL,
                    CLSCTX_INPROC,
                    __uuidof(IApplicationAssociationRegistration),
                    (void**)&pAAR);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pAAR->SetAppAsDefaultAll(ACTIVESEND_REGNAME);

            bRet = SUCCEEDED(hr);

            pAAR->Release();
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

According to the documentation, this feature works only for prior to Windows 8.

[image]

**Question:** What is the alternative for the same feature for Windows 8+?

Comment: The method used in Windows 10 is **IApplicationAssociationRegistrationInternal** which generates automatically the hash (I had answered with more details in another thread...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no real alternative, Microsoft does not want applications to change the defaults because of badly behaved 3rd-party applications.

If you want to go into undocumented land, a subkey in the Explorer key stores the "encrypted" default progid for each claimed file-extension.